Where do you add the code to automate adding users to Google Groups using AppScript? Google Forms script or (linked) Google Sheet script?
I have a spreadsheet with user information. As the administrator for my organization's workspace, I am trying to add the rows from the first column, which are the email addresses themselves, directly into the google group.
I have already tried following instructions on

https://developers.google.com/apps-script
https://medium.com/@Urwa.Shabir/automate-adding-members-to-google-group-from-google-sheets-google-apps-script-16ee6eb41c43

... and more.
Now, I get the following error:

GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to directory.members.insert failed with error: Invalid Input: memberKey addGroupMember

Now I am questioning whether I am simply putting the code in the wrong place. I added this script into the spreadsheet, however, maybe it needs to be done on google form script?
function addGroupMember(range, group) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 99999);
    var values = range.getValues();
    Logger.log(values[0][0]);;

  var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail("group@myorganization.org");

for(i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
    try {
      addMember(range[i][0], group);
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.error(e);
      continue;
    }   
  }
  
    var newMember = {email: range, 
                     role: "MEMBER",
                     delivery_settings: "NONE"};
    
    AdminDirectory.Members.insert(newMember, group);
  
}



It doesn't matter where you put the code as far as this issue is concerned.  There might be many errors, but on a cursory look, email: range,  should be email: values[i][0],. for(i = 0; i < range.length; i++) { should be for(let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { Also review https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/members/insert

Specifically, from the above documentation: group key The value can be the group's email address, group alias, or the unique group ID.. So, group should be:  var group="group@myorganization.org"

Ok the group ID I think works better like this, thank you. However, when I insert email: values[i][0],  into the script as suggested, the var newMember cannot be "defined". Is there something still incorrect with var newMember?

Quote the exact text of the error and not your own interpretation.  Also, when you address me, use @TheMaster - otherwise, I won't get notifications.
